# How to get Terraform arguments list by using keyboard shortcuts in Mac VScode? HashiCorp Terraform plugin does not work

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, terraform, shortcut

I have encountered a problem that when i try to check/get the arguments in Terraform blocks like resources, Terraform. My Mac Vscode does not work automatically shows up some argument list for me to choose. And I am wondering how to configure it and what's the combination of keyboard shortcuts to increase my efficiency?

[image: vsc screenshot]

I have installed the HarshiCorp Terraform plugin in Mac Vscode.

Answer (score 1):

You should [install Terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/downloads) on your machine before, then install [Hashicorp's official Terraform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform) extension, if it's already installed upgrade it (seems that [their bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-ls/issues/768) is fixed now)

Then, on your VS Code press `CMD+Shift+X` And make sure that your extension is enabled.

Also, try reloading your extension by reloading your window as their documentation states:

> You can reload the Terraform extension by opening the command palette
> and starting to type Reload. A list of commands will appear, select
> Reload Window. This will reload the Visual Studio Code window without
> closing down the entire editor, and without losing any work currently
> open in the editor.

---

After you install Terraform and the extension, you should have VS Code open in the same directory where you ran `terraform init` as it will load your locally installed modules and loads your providers' configuration. For example, if you are pulling modules from a private registry the module documentation may not detect your schemas and then it won't offer autocompletion capabilities.

If you still have issues refer to these links:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform#troubleshooting